# JDBC connection string SQL Server with JSP causes "Illegal escape character" error

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc, sql-server-2012

What would my connection string be if the name of my SQL Server 2012 is `JOSEAN\REGULUS` ?

```
"jdbc:sqlserver://JOSEAN\REGULUS;databasename = BD12272"
```

However, it caused a compilation error:

> Illegal escape character

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Are you getting an error?  what exactly do you mean by "not having results"?

Comment: If you're really doing this in a JSP, just...don't.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
"jdbc:sqlserver://JOSEAN;instanceName=REGULUS;databaseName=BD12272"
```

Answer (score 1):

The [java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html) says:

> A character preceded by a backslash (\) is an escape sequence and has
>   special meaning to the compiler. The following table shows the Java
>   escape sequences:
>
> - **\t**     Insert a tab in the text at this point.
> - **\b**     Insert a backspace in the text at this point.
> - **\n**     Insert a newline in the text at this point.
> - **\r**     Insert a carriage return in the text at this point.
> - **\f**     Insert a formfeed in the text at this point.
> - **\'**     Insert a single quote character in the text at this point.
> - **\"**     Insert a double quote character in the text at this point.
> - **\\** Insert a backslash character in the text at this point.

Your connection string has a backslash, so java expects a escape sequence and **\R** is not (Illegal escape character).

So, you must escape the backslash and your connection string should look like this:

```
"jdbc:sqlserver://JOSEAN\\REGULUS;databasename = BD12272"
```